# When it comes to Mexico, whom should be follow? – Benson, or Wells?

Tags: translation

Benson says “Meksikio” for the country, and “Meksiko” for “Mexico City”, whereas Wells (and Vikipedio) says “Meksiko” for the country, and “Meksik-Urbo” for “Mexico City”.

Comment: I've never heard Meksikio before, but I see why that would be a logical name.  Mexico follows the logic of Spain being the land of Spaniards, while countries like the US and Canada are the lands established by their speakers.  I guess it could either way and would depend on your ideological bent.

Answer (score 2):

This discussion is bigger than Wells vs Benson. Whole articles have been written to discuss this question. (Unfortunately, I am unable to locate one quickly at the moment.)

I believe that many Mexicans prefer *Meksiko* for the name of their country. In this article here, Bertilo explains the reasons for not saying *Meksikio* - even while explaining that the term is more precise.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/neoficialaj_afiksoj/sufiksoj/i.html

My own approach is to say both *Meksikio* and *Meksikurbo*, since both terms are clear and unambiguous. If someone says *Meksiko* or objects to my usage, I try my best to understand from context and don't make a big deal about it either way.

Answer (score 0):

Mexico = Meksiko

Mexico City = Meksik-urbo

All of these links use the word **Meksiko**:

http://uea.org/landoj?korektu=mx

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meksiko

http://www.esperanto-mexico.org/eo